# How to insert values from a table only if they do not exist already using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to read value from a table them insert it into another table only if the staring that I am trying to insert does not already exist in the table.

I have tried to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause but I get a syntax issue that i am unable to fix.

this is my query

```
SELECT Field1 FROM RSF
INSERT INTO result_codes(result_code_title, created_by)
VALUES (Field1, '2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE result_code_title = Field1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE` instead.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO result_codes(result_code_title, created_by)
SELECT Field1, '2'
FROM RSF
```

It detects via a primary key or unique index, if a row already exists and doesn't attempt to insert if this is the case.

Comment: just to make sure I get this clear. INSERT IGNORE works only if there if the column result_code_title is unique?

Comment: Or the created_by column, yes. Same applies to  `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 2):

The clause is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and not `SELECT ... INSERT INTO`. Therefore:

```
INSERT INTO result_codes( result_code_title, created_by )
SELECT Field1, '2'
FROM RSF
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE result_code_title = Field1;
```

I think that should work.

---

Since you only want to *insert only if the string doesn't already exist*; you should be better off using `INSERT INGORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO result_codes( result_code_title, created_by )
SELECT Field1, '2'
FROM RSF
```